# sample size justification in random forest or gradient boosting

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, sample-size, statistical-power, boosting

I was wondering about the method of sample size calculation/power analysis in random forest and gradient boosting models.

I already know the calculation of sample size using Gpower in regression model, but calculating sample size in the machine learning method is not familiar.